# Check for :contains on .Load()'s responseText

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I'd add a contains to check that the responseText coming back in the callback of a jQuery .load() contains a certain string of text:

```
   $("#ordersList").load("OrderHandler.ashx?action=" + action, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
   {
                   if(responseText)
                   {
                    // do something
                           return;
                   }

   });
```

so if responseText contains a certain string anywhere in the response that was sent back from the server I can perform appropriate processing in my callback function here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if(responseText.indexOf('mySearchString') > -1) {
         // do something
         return;
    }
```

Comment: weird, jQuery Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 does not show .indexOf...but looks like it can be applied on any jQuery element?

Comment: @coffeeAddict - It can be applied to a string. Not to a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for pointing out the obvious ;)  I think I'm just lacking sleep today and was frustrated when it was right in front of my face.

Answer (score 1):

The responseText is literally text.  You dont need Jquery for this if you just want to look for an instance anywhere in the string.

```
if(responseText.indexOf("the string im lookingfor") > -1)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks John.  I was thinking it was a jQuery object..but it's just a string param!  duh

Comment: This won't quite work, because the index returned may be 0, which will equate to `false`. You need to test that it is not less than 0, as `-1` is returned if there is no match.